# Runtime exception with jersey - java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to execute a RESTful web service deployed on tomcat using Jersey implementation.

Following is the resource class

@Path("/rest")
public class PatientResource {

```
PatientService patientService;

@GET
@Path("/patient/{patientId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Patient getPatientDetails(@PathParam("patientId") String patientId) {
    //return patientService.getPatientDetails(patientId);
    return new PatientService().getPatientDetails(patientId);
}

@GET
@Path("/patients")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PatientData<Patient> getAllPatients() {
    //return patientService.getAllPatients();
    return new PatientService().getAllPatients();
}
```

}

I have made necessary entries in web.xml and all necessary jars are available in classpath, however when application is started on tomcat and I enter the URL in browser, I get following exception

[Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findSerializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1148)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerFromAnnotation(BasicSerializerFactory.java:367)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)

Any idea how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably an inconsistency in the versions of Jersey and Jackson you are using at runtime .

What are your libs versions ?

Comment: Ypp it was the version problem. synced all jars to proper version and it is gone !!